# Data-binding in Widgets

Tags: backbone.js, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I am trying to data-bind a `app/Models/mymodel.js` in `app/widgets/mywidget/widget.xml`

`<Collection src="mymodel" instance="true" id="aModel" />`

I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] :  Script Error Couldn't find module: alloy/widgets/mywidget/models/mymodel for architecture: x86_64
```

Not specifying `WPATH` in `widget/ctrl.js` and `widget/style.tss` resulting in `Alloy.create*` methods pick up from `app/` controller or models.

Is there a way to specify to use `app/Model` in `widget/xml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Widgets are independent. They're supposed to be shared across apps. So having a dependency on the app, or a specific model, is not the way it is supposed to be and it is designed so it won't work for this reason.

If you've written the widget yourself specifically for this app remove it, and move code to a separate controller.

If you want to share the widget across apps and want to use a collection inside it, make an exported function and provide the collection to it.

In your widget create a model file with a generic name. Include that collection inside your widget.xml. Then in your widget.js create a method to import the collection

```
exports.setCollection = function(collection){
     $.myCollection.reset(collection.models);
}
```

Then in your controller including the widget:

```
$.myWidget.setCollection($.myOtherCollection);
```

This will set all models of the imported collection to the widget collection. Have an ID attribute that doesn't match? Do some converting in the `setCollection` method so ID does match. That way it is reusable across apps.

For example, your ID attribute is ObjectId, then you this:

```
exports.setCollection = function(collection, IdAttribute){
     _.each(collection, function(model){
          model.set({id: model.get(IdAttribute)}, {silent: true});
     });
     $.myCollection.reset(collection.models);
}
```

Then in your controller including the widget:

```
$.myWidget.setCollection($.myOtherCollection,'ObjectId');
```

Then you've transformed your collection and all should work